# Gecko or JavaScript for choose an option in ComboBox

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko

Please, I'm trying to choose an option in 'ComboBox', but the "optionElement.Selected = true;" doesn't work. Am I using it the right way? It's necessary make another command before? I have an auxiliary function and a stretch of the main function. Detail: "pdcme_cd_tipo_ac" is a 'TextBox':

```
// MAIN FUNCTION
// ... 

var optionElements = oGecko.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option");

foreach (GeckoOptionElement optionElement in optionElements)
{
    //2019-12-06 - Fabio I. - If the combo is "ID = #cd_type" (because it takes ALL options from ALL combos!);
    if (optionElement.Parent.Id == "#cd_type")
    {
        if (optionElement.Label.ToUpper() == "APPLICATION")
        {
            optionElement.Selected = true;
            SetTextInput_ID("pdcme_cd_tipo_ac", optionElement.Label);
            break;
        }
        else if (optionElement.Label.ToUpper() == "TOTAL RESCUE")
        {
            optionElement.Selected = true;
            SetTextInput_ID("pdcme_cd_tipo_ac", optionElement.Label);
            break;
        }
        else if (optionElement.Label.ToUpper() == "REDEMPTION LIQUID VALUE")
        {
            optionElement.Selected = true;
            SetTextInput_ID("pdcme_cd_tipo_ac", optionElement.Label);
            break;
        }

    // ...
    }
}

private bool SetTextInput_ID(string ID,
                             string ValueID)
{
    GeckoElement ele;

    try
    {
        ele = oGecko.Document.GetElementById(ID);

        if (ele == null) return false;

        if (ele.GetType().ToString() != "Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement") return false;

        ((GeckoInputElement)ele).Focus();
        ((GeckoInputElement)ele).Value = ValueID;
        ((GeckoInputElement)ele).Click();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jawad, I mean it doesn't click or doesn't select.

Comment: have you tried optionElement.Selected.SetAttribute("value", true);

Comment: @Jawad, within ''Selected' does't have the method "SetAttribute". Did you import any extra function in NuGet?

Comment: @Jawad, -> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'SetAttribute' and could not find any accessible 'SetAttribute' extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'bool' (is there a missing assembly usage policy or reference?)

Comment: optionElement.setAttribute("Selected", "true"); use a string instead of bool

Comment: @Jawad, sorry, no efectted... I put too: optionElement.Click(); AND                                    optionElement.Selected = true; ... but didn't do anything either...